# How to convert list of maps to list of objects

Tags: groovy

I have a `POJO` class like as below :-

```
public class Pojo {
   String param1
   List param2
   Map param3
   Boolean param4
   Integer param5
}
```

I have a `List` which contains `Map` objects with the same structure as like `Pojo` :-

```
List list = [
        [param1: "a", param2: ["a","b","c"], param3:[a:"a",b:"b",c:"c"], param4:true, param5:1],
        [param1: "b", param2: ["d","e","f"], param3:[d:"d",e:"e",f:"f"], param4:false, param5:2]
]
```

Now I want to convert this **list of maps** to **list of pojo objects**

Anyone have idea how to convert it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a one-liner....

```
// here's the class we want to convert to 
public class Pojo {
   String param1
   List param2
   Map param3
   Boolean param4
   Integer param5
}

// here the data we want to convert
List list = [
        [param1: "a", param2: ["a","b","c"], param3:[a:"a",b:"b",c:"c"], param4:true, param5:1],
        [param1: "b", param2: ["d","e","f"], param3:[d:"d",e:"e",f:"f"], param4:false, param5:2]
]

// this is the conversion
List<Pojo> pojos = list.collect { new Pojo(it) }
```

Comment: Yeah...Nice !!  I have already achieved it but your answer is just one line solution...Thanks.....:)

Comment: You can also do `List<Pojo> pojos = list.collect { it as Pojo }`

Comment: Or `List<Pojo> pojos = list*.asType(Pojo)`

Comment: @tim_yates I did not know that when `asType` is invoked on a `List` it passes `this` to the constructor of the target type. I can't wait to tell the lads down the local about this.

Comment: Don't miss the spread operator `*.` ;-)  And you need a new place to drink ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates you'd be a big hit here https://katcountryhub.com/2014/11/14/groovys-pub-dream-of-small-town-tavern-becomes-reality/