# How to convert list of maps to list of objects if list of maps has extra keys

Tags: object, arraylist, groovy, hashmap

My question is almost similar to [How to convert list of maps to list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142532/how-to-convert-list-of-maps-to-list-of-objects).

But the problem is now, I have `list` of `maps` where `maps` contains some extra keys which is not present in my `Pojo` class as property like as below :-

```
List list = [
    [param1: "a", param2: ["a","b","c"], param3:[a:"a",b:"b",c:"c"], param4:true, param5:1, param6: "pamra6",param7: "pamra7"],
    [param1: "b", param2: ["d","e","f"], param3:[d:"d",e:"e",f:"f"], param4:false, param5:2, param6: "pamra6",param7: "pamra7"]
]
```

In this `list` two extra keys `param6`, `param7` included where this is not exist in `Pojo` class, because in my scenario I'm considering only those property which present in the `Pojo`, I can't increase extra property in the `Pojo` class.

So when I'm going to convert this `list of maps` to `list of objects` as below :-

```
list.collect { new Pojo(it) }
```

it's throwing an error as :-

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: param6 for
>   class: Pojo

Which is absolutely correct, but when I'm converting like below :-

```
list.collect { it as  Pojo }
```

or

```
list*.asType(Pojo)
```

It's not throwing any error but when we going to get values like this :-

```
.each { pojo ->

  pojo.param1
  ------------
  ------------
}
```

Couldn't found any of these value. all values found as `null`.

When I'm examine converted `list of objects` using `.dump()`, it converted as `Pojo1_groovyProxy` like as proxy object..

So my question is, how to convert in this situation???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [Michael Easter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12704/michael-easter) and [tim_yates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509/tim-yates) suggestion, achieved this using as below :-

```
class Pojo {
 def param1
 def param2
 def param3
 def param4
 def param5

def static build(def map) {
    new Pojo(map.findAll { k, v -> k in Pojo.metaClass.properties*.name})
  }
}

def newList = list.collect { Pojo.build(it) }
```

Thanks for giving me big hint..:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it (which attempts to be resilient if `param6` were later added to the class):

(edit: much cleaner, thanks to [tim_yates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509/tim-yates))

```
class Pojo {
    def param1
    def param2
    def param3
    def param4
    def param5

    def static build(def map) {
        def fields = Pojo.declaredFields.findAll { !it.synthetic }*.name
        def keys = map.keySet().findAll { it in fields }
        def subMap = map.subMap(keys)
        new Pojo(subMap)
    }
}


def newList = list.collect { Pojo.build(it) }
```

Comment: Is it necessary to be `static build()` in `Pojo` class??? is there no prebuild method???

Comment: Instead of the matcher/declaredFields thing, can't you just do: `def fields = Pojo.declaredFields.findAll { !it.synthetic }*.name`

Comment: @tim_yates your point is giving me more clarification, before your suggestion I was using like `def static build(def map) {new Pojo(map.findAll { k, v -> k in Pojo.metaClass.properties*.name})}`....Is this correct too?????